# Override Boostrap in Angular App

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to override the default Twitter Bootstrap styles in my Angular application. I am using AngularJS v1.6.8.

My file structure looks like the following:

`*src
    *app
    *public
      *styles
        *global-styles.css
      *index.html`

I've placed the css I'd like to use to override Twitter Bootstrap styles in global-styles.css.

Currently, I am using "bootstrap-css-only" in order to leverage the default styles provided by Twitter Bootstrap.

I added my global-styles.css to my index.html like so:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <base href="/">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/global-styles.css">`

My custom styles don't show up on my index.html and/or on any of the components. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is because base href is set to "/" and failed to load your css altogether.
You can either remove base tag and use relative path:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/global-styles.css">
```

or set absolute path:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<base href="/">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ROOT_PATH/src/public/styles/global-styles.css">
```

note: you'll need to replace ROOT_PATH

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the new CSS classes you want to override that CSS classes you have to keep in a style.css file. I will work and just add !important in CSS class attributes.
.

Comment: I'd prefer not to use !important in my CSS. I'd rather in this case just be able to place the CSS file that has my custom CSS overwrite the baseline Twitter Bootstrap CSS via order that the files are loaded. I can't figure that out since the baseline Bootstrap CSS is coming from bootstrap-css-only.